How to Assign a Unique COM Port to a Zephyr USB CDC ACM Device for Consistent Identification?
I am working on a Zephyr project where I need to assign a unique COM port to a USB CDC ACM device such that I can consistently query this port from a different application. My current setup assigns ports like tty.usbmodem1101, tty.usbmodem101, etc., which vary each time the device is connected to a different port.

Modified the device tree to include a USB CDC ACM configuration.
Written application code to initialize the USB subsystem and bind the CDC ACM device.

&zephyr_udc0 {
    cdc_acm {
        compatible = "zephyr,cdc-acm-uart";
        label = "CDC_ACM";
        status = "okay";
    };
};

int main(void)
{
    const struct device *dev;
    int rc;
    if (IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_USB_DEVICE_STACK)) {
        dev = device_get_binding("CDC_ACM");
         if (dev == NULL) {
            printk("CDC ACM device not found\n");
            return;
        }
        rc = usb_enable(dc_status_cb);
        if (rc) {
            LOG_ERR("Failed to enable USB (%d)", rc);
            return rc;
        }
    }

...


Have you tried setting the unique serial number in the prj.conf file?
CONFIG_USB_DEVICE_SN="1234567890AB"

This worked, thank you very much. I am not sure how I missed that!
